# baresip bfcp module support sending video stream?

Tags: video-streaming, sip, baresip

Is it available BFCP in baresip? and how to choose BFCP video source on Baresip?

Normal Video calling using AVcodec is very well active.

but, I have some interest in BFCP modules.

because I want to sending 2 video stream into 1 call

so, my purpose make additional second video stream(BFCP)

but, I couldn't find video stream or source selection about bfcp module in 
baresip.

I analyze code about `call.h`, when normal sip video call is fired,
`sdp_media_rformat` method setting sdpmedia video stream.

but, `bfcp_start` function doesn't have `sdp_media_format`, and `video_start`...

so how could I match video stream source(h264) to BFCP?